# Generate serial number in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: Serail Number]

How can I generate serial number like in image in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

For all i know, out of the box mysql allows autoincrementing columns by 1.
maybe you can divide the number into two columns , use autoincrementation on the decimal part and update the other part manually

Comment: what do you recommend when he wants to wedge something between 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a reference of the following MYSQL query and generate serial numbers

```
select @prev_value := TotalLoanAmt, 
       @row_num := IF(@prev_value=TotalLoanAmt, @row_num + 1,1) AS RowNumber, 
       TotalLoanAmt
FROM Loan, (select @row_num := 0) x, (select @prev_value := '') y
order by TotalLoanAmt
```

;

Comment: Please note that "TotalLoanAmt" is field name and "Loan" is table name that you can replace with your own fieldname and tablename.

I tested this query on my local machine and it generates serial number column(RowNumber) and works like charm!